# Shopify & VueJs How to hide apiKey and apiPass

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, shopify

Im using shopify's admin API in VueJs to make some Api calls. The problem is that I'm fairly sure I have to send the Key and Password a long to get it work. Which means it's exposed on my site. How can i hide it? Or did I use a wrong setup?

I can't find this problem anywhere else, so im fairly sure i'm just stupid. Help! Here's what my code looks like.

```
async mounted () {
      let config = {
        headers: {
          'X-Shopify-Access-Token': 'Access-Token',
        }
    }
    let  apikey = 'apikey ';
    let  apipass = 'apipass ';
    let  url = 'url.myshopify.com';
    let  getrequest = '/admin/api/2020-01/products.json?limit=200';
      await axios.get('https://'+ apikey + apipass + '@' + url + getrequest, config)
        .then(response => this.products = response.data.products).catch( error => { console.log(error);      
      });

      this.sortAfterCategory();

      if(custombundle == true) {
        this.custombundle = true;
      }

      if(this.cart_count >= 3 && actualItems >= 3 || this.custombundle == true) {  
          return this.EnableAddToCartButton();
      }

    },
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
  });
```

Comment: You should make these calls from your backend. If you don't have a backend and your application is just a SPA, just build a tiny Node.js backend and use something like axios to make http requests. Else go to Azure Functions or AWS Lambda and use their serverless functions as your backend (both have secret stores).

Comment: There should only be an API key in your http call. This API key is set via a separate route - by sending your login details once through a secure login route. If login is successful, the backend responds with an API key which is stored locally on the device. This key is unique to the user and is sent as a Bearer token with every subsequent request, meaning your login details never have to be sent again - only that first time.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to install an App in your shop, and setup the App Proxy in that App. Once you do that, you can make calls from your front-end code using JS, and it is all secure and safe, and you can return all the Admin API data you want.

Comment: I don't know enough about proxies to make this work, and their documentation is really limited. Do you have any good source. On how to do it?

Comment: what if someone calls my proxy app pretending to be my shop?

Comment: What do you mean pretending? If you understand Proxy, you will understand that Shopify itself is taking the request, they are forming it, and they are sending it to your App. As such, they encrypt it so only you can decrypt it. So now how would someone pretend to do all that? Pretty much they won't. So why worry about that?